# Session bean data available after logout?

Tags: session, jsf

In a jboss seam application I have a session scoped bean (`<managed-bean-scope>session`) that is created and populated when a user arrives at the log-in page.

```
<page view-id="/jrnl/*">
   <action execute="#{applySkin.setSkinById}"/>
   <navigation>
     <redirect view-id="/login.xhtml"/>
   </navigation>
</page>
```

I've come to realize that I need that data after a user logs out and is redirected to the login page again. But identity.logout destroys the session and the bean.

Is there another way to scope this bean so that it persists for the user after logout, or otherwise pass a param for the redirect?

```
<navigation from-action="#{identity.logout}">
   <redirect view-id="/login.xhtml"/>
</navigation>
```

Comment: If you need Session-data after login out - it is located wrong in the session scoped bean. If it's about the template id choosen, I would put this to the database. Then you can always fetch it from there before login, and put it to the session scope later to avoid per-request loading.

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing the functional requirement to do so. The only way to obtain such session scoped data after the session is destroyed and a redirect is made is to pass them as query-string parameters, if possible or even store them in a verbose scoped bean like an application scoped bean prior to invalidating a session and making a redirect to the login page but then they will be shared across all other potential sessions - it fully depends upon the requirement.

Comment: Thx. I considered storing it in the DB but thought I'd investigate other options first. I don't think the application scope would be right as it should apply only to the current user. I think I'll look into passing as query-string params next.

Comment: Flash scope is another possibility. But indeed, all depends on the concrete functional requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the flash scope without luck. As a workaround, I moved the identity.logout into an action method. The method grabs the bean value, logs out, and then returns the bean value. I then use page navigation based on the returned value.